# monotonicity of binomial coefficient

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, optimization, binomial-coefficients

I am interested in
$$f(x):={k-1 \choose x-1} p^{x} (1-p)^{k-x}.$$

How do I find out in which Domain this function is monotonically increasing, in which it is monotonically decreasing? For which $x$ has the function a Maximum?

Maybe [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224102937/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52222.html) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one computes the ratio $f(x+1)/f(x)$, one sees that many simplifications occur, which make that $f(x+1)\gt f(x)$ is equivalent to $x\lt kp$. Hence $x\mapsto f(x)$ is increasing up to roughly $x=kp$, then decreasing.