# Binomial Coefficient: monotonically decreasing in this range?

Tags: probability, optimization, binomial-coefficients

relating to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847126/monotonicity-of-binomial-coefficient/847151#847151), I'd like to ask a further one.

Again we have $$f(x)={k-1 \choose x-1} p^x (1-p)^{k-x}$$

We know that this term is maximal for $x=kp$, before increasing, afterwards decreasing.

But what is, if we know that $kp \ll 1$ (for $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $n$ is not very relevant here) and $x$ can only take on constant values from $X$ (Independent from $n$). Then this would imply that $x \gg kp$ for all $x\in X$ and thus the function is decreasing in $X$, is this correct?

Stated differently, is it correct for $kp \ll 1$ and $x=O(1)$ for all $x\in X$, that this term above is monotonically decreasing in the range $X$?

**EDIT:**
Maybe I should ask my question differently, as I am not interested in the normal case for a fixed $x$ and fixed $k$, $p$. I know what's going on there. 
My Problem is, when I know that only asymptotically $x < kp$ (and not necessarily for small values of $n$), is it safe to assume that asymptotically $f$ is decreasing?

Comment: A function of $x$ decreasing when $x$ is constant? Please explain.

Comment: $x$ has a range $X$, where the Minimum and the Maximum value in this range are constants. So every possible value $x$ can have is constant, but in this range $X$, for smaller $x$ the term is bigger.

Comment: ?? Sorry... $ $

Comment: We know that $k$ and $p$ depend on $n$, such that for $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have that $kp \ll 1$. 

Further we have that $x$ can take some values from a range $X$, where all the values in $X$ are constants, thus Independent from $n$. 
Thus, for every possible value we have $x=O(1)$. 

Is it true that for all $x,y \in X$ it holds that:
$f(x)\geq f(y)$ for $x \leq y$ where $f$ is defined as this binomial term above.

Answer (score 2):

We know $f(x)>f(x+1)$ is equivalent to $x>kp$ or $x\ge \lceil kp\rceil.$ So $f$ is decreasing if $x\gt kp.$

If $kp \lt 1$ then $f$ is decreasing on $X=\{1,2,3,...\}.$
It is not necessary that $ kp<< 1.$

Comment: It is not necessary that $kp \ll 1$, I know. 
But if I know that $x=O(1)$ and I know that $kp \ll 1$, it is sufficient to know that $f$ is decreasing, for an asymptotic apprxomiation? Or is this not valid?

Comment: So again, for the ones who read this question and this answer.
What is written in this answer is absolutely clear for me and thus not at all my Problem.
My question was: If i only know that $kp \ll x$ (for big $n$), is it safe to assume that $f$ is decreasing in $x$?

Comment: where all the values in X are constants, thus Independent from n. Thus, for every possible value we have x=O(1).

Comment: This is unclear. I am left to guess what you mean. Use $k_n,p_n,f_n$ since they depend on $n$. $f_n$ is defined on $\{1,2,...,k_n\}.$ You have a subset $X$ of this domain that does not change with the changing values of $k_n.$ So maybe $k_n$ is increasing? If $k_np_n \to c\lt 1$ then there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $n \gt N, k_np_n \lt 1.$ Then from my Answer, $f_n,$ for all $n \gt N,$ is decreasing at each point it is defined and so on $X.$ Is this the Poisson approx. to the binomial?